# Can Windows Server 2008 R2 / 2012 join a homegroup?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, homegroup, windows-server-2012

A simple question that I couldn't find an answer to through Google search - **can Windows Server** (some recent version) **join a homegroup**?

Comment: Wasn't the concept of a Homegroup was introduced in Windows 7/Windows 2008 R2 anyways?  Considering Windows 2012 has not been released its a little early for this question.

Comment: It was introduced with Windows 7. I don't know if it's also supported in 2008 R2. WS2012 has reached the RTM state and there has been a RC which usually means the software is feature complete (or very near to that). So if anyone tried that, they could possibly answer this question.

Comment: If you have access to the software I would just test it.  Based on N_Lindz answer and supported article, it sounds like `Homegroup` is likely a Windows 7/Windows 8 only feature, and not supported by the Windows Server versions.  Windows Home Server ( 2011 ) is more a home user Windows version then business class which is the reason its supported.

Answer (score 2):

From what I’ve been able to find online it looks like the ability to join Homegroups is limited to Windows 7 (and newer) and Windows Home Server (2011).

[This site](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/File-sharing-essentials) states that “Homegroups aren’t available on Windows Server 2008 R2.”

Unfortunately I can’t seem to find any Microsoft sites that state if homegroups are available in Windows Server 2012.