# How to get Server 2008 on a network with Windows 7 machines

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-server-2008

I have a few Windows 7 computers in the house that are all part of a home group, we can Remote Desktop onto them, fileshare, etc. How can I get a Windows 2008 Server networked to these computers? I just need it to have the same status as the Windows 7 computers.

I followed one path incorrectly, which was to set up Active Directory, DHCP, and DNS on the Server, but when I got to the end I realized this this is not really what I want, I don't need the server box to be in charge of anything, I just want to see it.

The image is my network. As I said, the Windows 7 computers are all seeing eachother as part of a home group. But the Windows 2008 computer can join the home group. Is there an alternative to home groups that I need to use?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2008 R2 Server doesn't support joining HomeGroups.

Perhaps see: [Can Windows Server 2008 R2 / 2012 join a homegroup?](https://superuser.com/questions/463871/can-windows-server-2008-r2-2012-join-a-homegroup)

Instead, removed AD, DNS, DHCP, etc, and just join the server to the same Workgroup the Windows 7 machines belong to.

Comment: yeah, I saw that questions, but it seems to contradict this KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2521416. But I'm fine with abandoning the HomeGroup and using a Workgroup. So I will try to *join the server to the same Workgroup the Windows 7 machines belong to.* Thanks.